# How to make a dynamic valueBox in Flexdashboards in R

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to build a panel where when selecting a State in a drop-down list the value of a valueBox dynamically change according to the column value in the database, but in every attempt I get an error return. Below, the code used:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
 
UF = c('AC', 'AM', 'AP', 'BA', 'CE', 'ES', 'PB', 'PE')
Column = c(30, 200, 7, 12, 854, 2, 78, 965)
df <- data.frame(UF,Coluna)

Row {data-width=200 .sidebar}
--------------------------------------------------------------

{r}
selectInput(inputId = "states",
            label="Select State:",
            choices = unique(df$UF),
            selected = "",
            multiple=FALSE
            )
Row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
{r}
renderValueBox({
b <- df %>%
  filter(UF %in% input$states) %>%
  select(df$Column)

valueBox(value = b, icon = "fa-users")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have a couple of mistakes here:

1. You have some misspelling of variable names.
2. You didn't load all the required libraries.
3. You had the wrong {dplyr} grammar for select.

After fixing everything, here is the working code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
UF = c('AC', 'AM', 'AP', 'BA', 'CE', 'ES', 'PB', 'PE')
Column = c(30, 200, 7, 12, 854, 2, 78, 965)
df <- data.frame(UF,Column)
```

Row {data-width=200 .sidebar}
--------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "states",
            label="Select State:",
            choices = unique(df$UF),
            selected = "",
            multiple=FALSE
            )
```

Row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
renderValueBox({
b <- df %>%
  filter(UF %in% input$states) %>%
  select(Column)

valueBox(value = b, icon = "fa-users")
})
```
````